I exported my ROV model from SolidWorks to Simscape. Now I have my model in Simscape, but I don't know what else I can do
I added a transform sensor so that I can see the gravity influencing my body, however I want my ROV to move in the simulation in the 3 axes: x, y and z. I heard that I need to create an environment for it, but I don't know what, or how, to do all that.
How to move and rotate the model in the simulation?

